# Novice programming fork process child grandchild great-grand child

Tags: process, fork

Crazy with fork process. I advanced a lot with the following work process still not with the correct result.
The idea is that the great-grand child is displayed after the child is closed. I think the problem is that i have to integrate i%6 in i%2 but i tried and no more ideas.

The result has to be: Show all the childs requested, then show the grandchild pairs and then the great-grandchilds por the grandchilds divisible by 6.
For example: Child 2, grandchild 20 = total 22.
And then total of intermediates.

Thanks so much. I'm desperated with that. hours and hours.

Best regards,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "rutines.h"


void show_help();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int p,pid[100];
    int d=10;
    int e=100;
    int fills;
    int status;
    int sumador;
    char msg[MAXSTR];

    if (argc>1)
    fills=atoi(argv[1]);
    if (argc==1)
    {
        show_help("Error");
        exit(1);
    }


    // Creem N processos fill
    for(p=1;p<fills+1;p++)
    {
        status=0;       
        pid[p] = fork();
        if (pid[p]<0)
            error("Error");
        else
            if (pid[p]==0)
            {
            sprintf(msg, "CHILD process %d creat -> Ordre: %d Pare: %d.\n",getpid(),p,getppid());
                write_string(msg,"");

                /* Proces del fill */
                if (p%2 == 0)
                {
                    // Creant al net
                    pid[p] = fork();
                    if (pid[p]<0)
                        error("Error");
                    else

                        if (pid[p]==0)
                        {
                        sprintf(msg, "  GRANDCHILD process %d creat -> Ordre: %d Pare: %d.\n",getpid(),p*d,getppid());
                        write_string(msg,"");

                            if (p%6 == 0)
                            {
                            //Creant el besnet
                            pid[p] = fork();
                            if (pid[p]<0)
                                error("Error");
                            else

                            if (pid[p]==0)
                            {
                            sprintf(msg, "    GREAT-GRAND CHILD process %d creat -> Ordre: %d Pare: %d \n",getpid(),p*e,getppid());
                            write_string(msg,"");

                                exit(p*100); //Besnet finalitzat
                            }
                            else
                                wait(&status);  
                                exit(WEXITSTATUS(status)+p*10); //Net finalitzat
                            }
                            else                                
                                exit(p*10);

                        }
                        else
                        wait(&status);
                        exit(WEXITSTATUS(status)+p); 

                    }
                    else
                        exit(p);

                }
                else
                wait(&status);
                sprintf(msg, "CHILD process acabat %d -> %d \n\n",getpid(),WEXITSTATUS(status));
                write_string(msg,"");


    sumador=sumador+WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }



    sprintf(msg, "Proces principal pare %d -> Total return values: %d.\n",getpid(),sumador);
    write_string(msg,"");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void show_help(char *err_message)
{
    write_string(err_message,"");
    write_string("Us de Pas1ok","");
}
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Now the code works well.I have checked it with the teacher. But i have a mistake when i fisnished the child process. It shows the father of all children and must show the children.I'm using the command sprintf getpid() and shows the getppid(). Any idea?